# Int(1digit) to char without any function

Tags: c++, c

I know there are similar questions answered but I did not find the answer I am looking for.

Is there any short and simple way of converting an integer(1digit) to char? Something similar to how we do it with char to int, just by adding `+'0'`

Comment: Are you looking to _cast_ an `int` to a `char` or _convert_ it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
int i = 8;
char ch = i+'0';
std::cout << ch << '\n';
```

Comment: No, `+'0'` is how you convert from int to char. `-'0'` is how you convert from char to int.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are asking how to go from `'9'` to `9`, just apply the inverse operation, i.e., subtract `'0'`:

```
char digit= value + '0';
int value= digit - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

See, the reason why you subtract '0' to a `char` (Example: '9') to convert it to an `int` is because the ASCII value of 0 is 48, 1 is 49 and so on till 9 which is 57. So when you do a '9' - '0' you are basically doing a 57-48 which equals 9. So you can use this logic any way you want.

Am just putting this out there so that you could understand the funda.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else said, a`+'0'` gives you what you want, but if you're interested in why this works:

The `char` datatype is actually just a number, between 0 and 255, each representing a different character. If you look at an ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif), you'll see that `'0'` is represented by the number `48`, so when you're doing `0+'0'`, you're getting back 48, and `9+'0'` is equivalent to `9+48`, giving you `57`, which you can see on the table represents that character `'9'`. You can apply the same principle with letters (e.g. add `'A'` to convert a number to a letter).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
int i = 5;
char x = (char)('0' + i); // x = '5'
```

Comment: deprecated method of typecasting not recommended in c++. It's always safe to use streams.

Comment: @ken Can you elaborate a bit?  I'm a bit rusty on my C++, what is the best way of doing an explicit cast between primitive types then?  Also, what's this about streams.

Comment: #include <sstream>
int main()
{
    char* str = "1234";
    std::stringstream s_str( str );
    int i;
    s_str >> i;
} -----------------As streams are type safe we should always prefer them even though the foot print of program may increase and also the style which you have proposed is a 'C' style of type casting.

Answer (score 0):

Stick these in a header file:

```
char to_char( const int& x )
{
    return '0' + x;
}
int to_int( const char& c )
{
    return c - '0';
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the parameters being const references?

Comment: You're right. There is no need for it to be. I was thinking of compile time optimizations, but const references are not really required for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either `+48` or `+'0'`, they both work. The difference between integer `0` and character `'0'` is integer 48. Just remember that.